# Javascript box that takes answer and updates

Tags: javascript

I've gone over this for hours trying different things and can't get it to work, I've made a dice that rolls every 10 seconds, the timer and the dice roll shows on screen and constantly updates the roll. I want to make a box that shows the previous 5 rolls of the dice and constantly updates. Not sure if I have to make separate function or add it to my existing function. Here is what I have so far.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

   var timeInSecs;
   var ticker;

   function startTimer(secs) {
       timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
       ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000); 
   }

   function tick( ) {
       var secs = timeInSecs;

       if (secs > 0) {
           timeInSecs--; 
       }

       else {
           var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
           var status = document.getElementById("status");
           var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
           var diceTotal = d1;
           die1.innerHTML = d1;
           status.innerHTML = "Dice Roll "+diceTotal+".";
           clearInterval(ticker);
           startTimer(0000010);  // start again
       }


       var mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
       secs %= 60;
       var pretty = ( (mins < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + mins + ":" + ( (secs < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + secs;
       document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = pretty;
    }

    startTimer(0000010);  

</script>
```

Comment: Could you include your current html as well? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to do `status.innerHTML += "Dice Roll "+diceTotal+".<br>";` I guess you want to append not just replace

Comment: `setInterval` with a string? :-(

Comment: <div id="UpCounter"></div>
 <div id="die1" class="dice">0</div>
 <h2 id="status" style="clear:centre;"></h2>

thats all in the body of my html, it runs perfectly, just need to make a box that stores the previous dice rolls, and thats where im stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to have 5 predefined divs and have them cleared/filled dynamically.
Another option is to keep the roll history in an array and fill the 'history element' from that array.

For example:

```
rolls.push(d1); //add roll to history
if(rolls.length > maxrollhistory)
     rolls.shift();            
die1.innerHTML = 'Previous rolls: ' + rolls.reduce(function(prev,cur){return '<span class="rollhistory">' + cur + ' </span>' + prev; }, '');
```

where `rolls` is the array containing the history. (rollhistory is a class I made up to format the results).

In the underlying example I took the liberty of restructuring the program to display the above ([click here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhwzxhpo/) ) :

```
var die1 = document.getElementById("die1"),
    status = document.getElementById("status");

function startTimer(secs) {

    var timeInSecs = parseInt(secs),        
        rolls = [],
        rem = 0, 
        maxrollhistory = 5,    
        roll = function(){
            var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            rolls.push(d1); //add roll to history
            if(rolls.length > maxrollhistory)
                rolls.shift();            
            die1.innerHTML = 'Previous rolls: ' + rolls.reduce(function(prev,cur){return '<span class="rollhistory">' + cur + ' </span>' + prev; }, '');
            status.innerHTML = "Dice Roll "+ d1 +".";
        },    
        tick = function(){       
            if (--rem <= 0) {
                rem = timeInSecs;
                roll();
            }

            var secs = rem;
            var mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
            secs %= 60;
            var pretty = ( (mins < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + mins + ":" + ( (secs < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + secs;
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = pretty;

            setTimeout(tick,1000);
        }

    tick();
}

startTimer(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to append. Check the snippet added  `status.innerHTML += "Dice Roll "+diceTotal+".<br>";`

```js
var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer(secs) {
  timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
  ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000); 
}

function tick( ) {
  var secs = timeInSecs;

  if (secs > 0) {
    timeInSecs--; 
  }

  else {
    var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var diceTotal = d1;
    die1.innerHTML = d1;
    status.innerHTML = "Dice Roll "+diceTotal+".<br>" +status.innerHTML;
    clearInterval(ticker);
    startTimer(0000010);  // start again
  }


  var mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
  secs %= 60;
  var pretty = ( (mins < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + mins + ":" + ( (secs < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + secs;
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = pretty;
}

startTimer(0000010);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div> <div id="die1" class="dice">0</div> <h2 id="status" style="clear:centre;"></h2>
```